# Why can't I erase all element of vector like this?

Tags: c++

My crashed source code was here:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int>::iterator iter , tempIt;
int main() {
    vector<int> cont(3, 5);
    for (iter = cont.begin() ; iter != cont.end() ; ) {
        tempIt = iter;
        ++iter;
        cont.erase(tempIt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It always fail when erase the last element.

Comment: You do `++iter` and then erase that, and then check that it's equal to `cont.end()`... `end` is one past the real end of the vector.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? _"erasing elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container to relocate all the elements after the segment erased to their new positions. "_ [(source)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

Comment: Because that's how `std::vector` is specified. If you need erase in middle, you probably don't want a `vector`.

Comment: FYI, the standard way to write your loop body is `{ iter = cont.erase(iter); }`.

Comment: Note that in this case, you can just do `cont.clear();`

Answer (score 4):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase:

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

Thus the erasure invalidates your `iter` iterator, and you have undefined behaviour after that.